# Converting time in string format to time stamp format does not work in Pyspark. It throws null

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, timestamp

My dataset:

```
+--------------------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------------+--------+-------+---------+--------------------+
|          event_time|event_type|product_id|        category_id|       category_code|   brand|  price|  user_id|        user_session|
+--------------------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------------+--------+-------+---------+--------------------+
|2019-10-01 00:00:...|      view|  44600062|2103807459595387724|                null|shiseido|  35.79|541312140|72d76fde-8bb3-4e0...|
|2019-10-01 00:00:...|      view|   3900821|2053013552326770905|appliances.enviro...|    aqua|  33.20|554748717|9333dfbd-b87a-470...|
|2019-10-01 00:00:...|      view|  17200506|2053013559792632471|furniture.living_...|    null| 543.10|519107250|566511c2-e2e3-422...|
|2019-10-01 00:00:...|      view|   1307067|2053013558920217191|  computers.notebook|  lenovo| 251.74|550050854|7c90fc70-0e80-459...|
|2019-10-01 00:00:...|      view|   1004237|2053013555631882655|electronics.smart...|   apple|1081.98|535871217|c6bd7419-2748-4c5...|
|2019-10-01 00:00:...|      view|   1480613|2053013561092866779|   computers.desktop|  pulser| 908.62|512742880|0d0d91c2-c9c2-4e8...|
```

I am trying to convert event_time column to timestamp format, but it throws null. Tried several approches but could not fix it yet. Any help or suggestions is appreciated ?

```
root
 |-- event_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- category_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- category_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- brand: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_session: string (nullable = true)
```

Approach 1:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
df = df.withColumn("eventTimeStamp", 
to_timestamp('event_time','yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'))
df.select('eventTimeStamp','event_time').show(20, 
truncate=False)



+--------------+-----------------------+
|eventTimeStamp|event_time             |
+--------------+-----------------------+
|null          |2019-10-01 00:00:00 UTC|
|null          |2019-10-01 00:00:00 UTC|
|null          |2019-10-01 00:00:01 UTC|
|null          |2019-10-01 00:00:01 UTC|
|null          |2019-10-01 00:00:04 UTC|
|null          |2019-10-01 00:00:05 UTC|
|null          |2019-10-01 00:00:08 UTC|
|null          |2019-10-01 00:00:08 UTC|
|null          |2019-10-01 00:00:10 UTC|
|null          |2019-10-01 00:00:11 UTC|
|null          |2019-10-01 00:00:11 UTC|
|null          |2019-10-01 00:00:11 UTC|
```

Approach 2:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, countDistinct

df = df.withColumn("Day", date_format(col("event_time"), "EEEE"))
df.show()



+--------------------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------------+--------+-------+---------+--------------------+----+
|          event_time|event_type|product_id|        category_id|       category_code|   brand|  price|  user_id|        user_session| Day|
+--------------------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------------+--------+-------+---------+--------------------+----+
|2019-10-01 00:00:...|      view|  44600062|2103807459595387724|                null|shiseido|  35.79|541312140|72d76fde-8bb3-4e0...|null|
|2019-10-01 00:00:...|      view|   3900821|2053013552326770905|appliances.enviro...|    aqua|   33.2|554748717|9333dfbd-b87a-470...|null|
|2019-10-01 00:00:...|      view|  17200506|2053013559792632471|furniture.living_...|    null|  543.1|519107250|566511c2-e2e3-422...|null|
|2019-10-01 00:00:...|      view|   1307067|2053013558920217191|  computers.notebook|  lenovo| 251.74|550050854|7c90fc70-0e80-459...|null|
|2019-10-01 00:00:...|      view|   1004237|2053013555631882655|electronics.smart...|   apple|1081.98|535871217|c6bd7419-2748-4c5...|null|
```

Please suggest how shall I fix the null values being generated?

Comment: Am using spark v2.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should add timezone part in the pattern of the timestamp. Approach 1 could be written as following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp

df = (df
      .withColumn("eventTimeStamp",
                  to_timestamp('event_time', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz')))
df.select('eventTimeStamp','event_time').show(20, truncate=False)

+-------------------+-----------------------+
|eventTimeStamp     |event_time             |
+-------------------+-----------------------+
|2019-10-01 00:00:00|2019-10-01 00:00:00 UTC|
|2019-10-01 00:00:00|2019-10-01 00:00:00 UTC|
+-------------------+-----------------------+
```